# Use Views instead of a node template for some node types

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I would like to replace the default display of some custom node types using views in Drupal 7.

For example, I have a view taking as first arguments a node id.
I want this view to be used instead of the default theme template when visiting ?q=node/NID if the node NID is of a certain custom type.

Being able to add the view result at the bottom of the content of the node page would be good too.

Is this possible? How should I do, which modules should I use?

Answer (score 0):

Could use the contemplete module and call the view programitically.

Answer (score 0):

I found a very simple solution: create a block for the view, then as argument for the block select the following parameters:
"Provide default argument" -> "node id from URL" -> Validate by node type.
I then added the block in the content section.
Thanks to this, the view is only displayed on the right pages!